# get json response using jquery form plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-forms-plugin

I'm using jquery form plugin in order to send ajax forms to server.
I check errors on server and send json object which contains several fields.

JSON response looks like this

```
{ "error1" : "true", "error2" : "false" }
```

But how to check in javascript function?

I'm trying like this but it doesn't work

```
var options = {
        url: 'registration.html',
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            alert(obj);
        }
    };
$("#registrationForm").ajaxForm(options);
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: How does it not work? No alert? An error?

Comment: @bjb568 Yes. There is no alert at all.

Comment: Nope. Browser's console is clear.

Comment: Then success doesn't fire.

Comment: I see. Hm. But why? Also it seems submit doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Add an error event to the ajax as following

```
  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
  }
```

This will help you figure out the current issue.

Comment: Erm...What is xhr & thrownError? I mean - what answer server should provide?

Comment: No they are returned by the ajax if any error occurs

Comment: Oh! I see. So they are here by default.